# What does !A mean in traceroute?

Tags: networking

```
Store_85000#traceroute 4.2.2.2 source vlan 1
Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to b.resolvers.Level3.net (4.2.2.2)
VRF info: (vrf in name/id, vrf out name/id)
1 10.32.5.57 76 msec 68 msec 68 msec
2 10.32.5.57 !A  *  !A 
Store_85000#
```

Comment: I googled.  This was the first hit:  https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10557426/traceroute  I'm not the person who downvoted you, but if you're wondering why someone else did, well....

Answer (score 5):

`!A` means `Administratively prohibited`

Here's a list of some common traceroute characters:

```
*    The probe timed out
A    Administratively prohibited (example, access-list)
Q    Source quench (destination too busy)
I    User interrupted test
U    Port unreachable
H    Host unreachable
N    Network unreachable
P    Protocol Unreachable
T    Timeout
?    Unknown packet type
```

[Source](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-121-mainline/12778-ping-traceroute.html)